# Clicking element does not display content

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get the words "breakfast", "lunch", "dinner" and "snacks/other" to show when I press the corresponding word on the menu. Problem is it's hiding all the words and not showing anything. I've scanned for bugs and cannot find anything, scoured the web and nothing.

Here's my HTML for the menu:

```
<div id="menu">
    <p>
        <span id="menubreakfast">Breakfasts | </span>
        <span id="menulunch">Lunches | </span>
        <span id="menudinner">Dinners | </span>
        <span id="menusnack">Snacks/Other</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Here's my HTML for the "pages" or words I want to show:

```
<div id="pagebreakfast" class="page">
    BREAKFAST
</div>
<div id="pagelunch" class="page">
    LUNCH
</div>
<div id="pagedinner" class="page">
    DINNER
</div>
<div id="pagesnack" class="page">
    SNACKS/OTHER
</div>
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menubreakfast').click(function(){
        $('.page').hide();
        $('#pagebreakfast').show();
    });
    $('#menulunch').click(function(){
        $('.page').hide();
        $('#pagelunch').show();
    });
    $('#menudinner').click(function(){
        $('.page').hide();
        $('#pagedinner').show();
    });
    $('#menusnack').click(function(){
        $('.page').hide();
        $('#pagesnack').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried making the ID of the divs?

Comment: Ok next time pls check it on a simple code editor like JSFiddle. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/abogal6274/2d8tohzw/4/) it is. Your code actually works.

Comment: Like "pagedinner" and "pagesnack", yes.

Comment: Can you please rephrase what you want? Cause you exactly said in your question: I'm trying to get the words "breakfast" "lunch" "dinner" and "snacks/other" to show when I press the corresponding word on the menu.   And that is what it does.

Comment: It's not working here: http://bit.ly/1NzeaAx

Comment: Are you saying the link i gave you is not working?

Comment: This is the page I'm using http://bit.ly/1NzeaAx

Comment: It is working on the JSFiddle but not the page..

Comment: Check if the anwser below works. If not your not importing JQuery, and i will post an anwser on how to import JQuery. Tell me if the below anwser works

Comment: Yes, the below works. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok Awesome! Have fun coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple to make it using class and data attribute

```
 <p>
     <span class="selectDivToShow" data-divToShow="pagebreakfast" id="menubreakfast">Breakfasts | </span>
     <span class="selectDivToShow" data-divToShow="pagelunch"  id="menulunch">Lunches | </span>
     <span class="selectDivToShow" data-divToShow="pagedinner"  id="menudinner">Dinners | </span>
     <span class="selectDivToShow" data-divToShow="pagesnack"  id="menusnack">Snacks/Other</span>
 </p>
```

and in js use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.selectDivToShow').on('click' , function(){
     var DivToShow = $(this).attr('data-divToShow');
     $('.page').not('#'+DivToShow).hide();
     $('#'+DivToShow).slideToggle();
   });
});
```

Comment: @JasonCastillo if you don't need to slideToggle and must be one of divs be visible you can use slideDown(); instead of slideToggle();